# How to shorten paths when accessing linked-server objects in SQL

Tags: sql, alias, linked-server

Is there a way to shorted access paths in SQL? I am thinking something similar to alias's but I don't know how to ask this question in google to get the appropriate application of alias'ing

This:

```
  select * from ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableName
```

To:

```
  declare @RDB as RemoteDatabaseObject
  set @RDB = ServerName.DBName.dbo

  select * from @RDB.TableName
```

I know this doesnt work, but I want to know if there is a way to alias objects that have long paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for SYNONYM?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't even know that was available.

Answer (score -1):

Aliasing works for what you're wanting here.

```
SELECT * FROM ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableName AS myAlias
```

The cool thing is that you can almost always use AS in the middle of sql statements.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: This is not what he is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

Other than using dynamic SQL, I dont think of any way which makes this possible.